# static assert if a header is included in another header but not a cpp

Tags: c++, windows, c++17

I have a c++ library which uses some functions from `windows.h`, and there is a utility header which defines conversions for some weird windows types into standard c++.

I'm wondering if there is a way to assert if the utilities are included into another header. The idea is to only include the utilities into `.cpp` files so that we don't taint the rest of the codebase with `windows.h` and windows types and the problems associated with including that (min/max, etc).

Comment: Can you explain a bit detailed? As I understand you don't need to assert. Why do you need this?

Comment: we want to keep windows types out of our ABI, so by rule we don't include anything that includes window.h into header files. It would be nice if we could find a way for the compiler to enforce that.

Comment: Can you check the header guard of `windows.h` with an `#ifdef` block?

Comment: @OnurTuna yup! Thanks!

Comment: I'm putting it to answers so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the header guard of `windows.h` is defined with an `#ifdef` block.

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS_
static_assert(false, "Don't include windows.h in header files!");
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's included in another header, that's because a cpp file is including it somewhere. So every code end up in a cpp file eventually.

You may want to look into module ts, which had not the transitive nature of headers, and any importing code won't import your module's imports.

---

If you can't use modules and still want to encapsulate headers by only allowing it in some places, you could place that header in a special directory, then only add that include directory on some allowed targets. If any other "disallowed" targets which don't have that include directory tries to include it, then a compilation error will occur.

Note that all cpp files that don't have that include directory will fail to include the header. But it's an advantage rather than an inconvenient: you will have to explicitly add it to your build system, making easy to spot such code.

Here's the directory structure:

```
- src/
    a.cpp
    b.cpp
   - include/       
     - private-header/
        - windows/
            windows-conversion.h
```

Here's an example with CMake:

```
add_library(using-windows-headers INTERFACE)
target_include_directory(using-windows-headers INTERFACE include/private-header/windows)
```

Then, on a per-target basis, you can link the target:

```
target_link_libraries(some-module PRIVATE using-windows-headers)
```

Be aware that this will work only if you put `PRIVATE` there, so any other dependent targets won't have the include directory.